# Codename one Facebook login can't get the login form

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, codenameone

I followed this tutorial https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-3.html 
when building my codename one project and I keep getting this error instead of the facebook login form 
Non connecté(e): Vous n’êtes pas connecté(e) : veuillez vous identifier avant de réessayer.
which basically translates to Not conncted you have to connect, when I don't even get the login form to connect.
I am suspecting the Facebook for developpers is there a new way to configure my app on it, because the tutorial had an old version

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following a more up to date version of the facebook connect instructions which are available in the [developer guide's misc section](http://codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html).

Comment: I followed that guide and same error, I even tried this project https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/tree/master/FacebookDemo ,can you provide me with Facebook app id and secret id that works since I tried making different apps on facebook developper and all their ids gave me the same error

Comment: Id's and secrets are private. This setup process is generally painful the first time around. Make sure you've set this in the code and that you have a proper internet connection. Check out the console for error messages as well.